# How to apply product filters from homepage

Tags: magento2, filter

I want a functionality in which I want a filter form in homepage. When a customer submit that form it should redirect to a category page with the products filtered by their selection in from.

**Suppose**

> we have 2 attributes: Player level & Gender. When customer select their option from form and submit form, then customer should
>   redirect to the category with filtered products.

Till now I have prepared a form with required attributes in homepage. And on its submission I am getting its value in separate controller.

Please let me know the solutions for it.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you post your code

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I don't have any Idea how to proceed further. I have just created a form in Homepage with the required attribute. Now I want a solution for How to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to keep the form field names same as the attribute code in your magento, e.g. if you have a color attribute which you want to add to your form, use it as `<select name='color'><option></option></select>`
Then, get the values in your controller post action, loop through all selected attributes and values like,

```
$data = YOUR_POST_DATA;
$collection = YOUR_PRODUCT_COLLECTION(WITH_CATEGORY_FILTER);
$filter = array();
foreach ($data as $attributeCode => $value) {
    $filter[] = array(
        'attribute' => $attributeCode,
        'eq'    => $value
    );
}

if (count($filter) > 0) {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
}
```

This way you will get collection of products with selected attribute values.

Now to put the collection to your `PHTML` file,
You have to create a `Block` which extends Magento's Product List Block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.
Now, take all the content of `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/catalo‌​g/product/list.phtml` to your `phtml` file.
Replace `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();` with your custom collection.

Comment: This is giving me the list of all the products but how to show them in listed format as in "Product listing page".

Comment: You can refer to Magento's default `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_TEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file.

Comment: How I can use list.phtml file for my filtered page?

Comment: Don't use the file but the code of the file. It will give you structure of the list page. You just need to update `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();` with your product collection.

Comment: I have tried by doing that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the other files I need to use for it? Do I need to make some changes in layout file?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal, updated answer, please check.